# Function and stored procedure can't have same name?

Tags: coldfusion

I wrote a function:

```
function getArtists(where='', artistactive = true){
   //yadayada
   return artists;
}
```

and included it, in a template, *after* the following

```
<cfstoredproc datasource="#request.dsn#" procedure="GetArtists">
    <cfprocresult name="GetArtists">
</cfstoredproc>
```

This produces an error:

> Routines cannot be declared more than once. The routine getArtists has
>   been declared twice in different templates

Ok, so question 1: ColdFusion thinks that a function and a stored procedure are both 'routines' and cannot be declared twice?

So, next thing I did was to include my functions template *before* the stored procedure... and it seems to be fine, with that.

Question 2: what gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should believe the error. In testing your code I get no error when declaring the function and then calling a stored proc of the same name. when I dump out the variables scope using `<cfdump var="#variables#">` I *only* see the result set (not the function) because the function has been overwritten by the result set. If I try to call the function after declaring the function and then overwriting it I get `"Incorrect entity type for being a function"` as my error.

Remember that the CF Compiler goes through your code and compiles UDFs and components first. They are not compiled at runtime. The error you are referencing occurs during the compile, not the runtime. For this reason I think it is more likely that your UDF routine *is actually being included* more than once. Take a look at the debug information at the bottom and search for that file and see if this is the case - or examine custom tag calls and other ways where files are doubled.

Advice: As a rule UDF should be declared in their own space (onRequest() is a good spot for it) and should be protected from this sort of thing. I use a variable like "lib" and store my functions (which are members of objects just like in Java) as lib.function1(), lib.function2(). The way you are doing it leads to unpredictability. That last is just my Opinion - trying to help. :)

Comment: *occurs during the compile* Yes, and that related to why the error only occurs when the include is called *after* cfstoredproc.  Like you said, functions are stored in the `variables` scope too, so I am guessing CF first checks that scope - sees a variable with same name already exists - and throws an error (though not a completely accurate one).

Comment: php guy, not used to functions being 'stored in variables'... is there anything to declare, when doing lib.function? or do you just name your functions like lib.function and call it, as such? result = lib.function(somevar);

Comment: @DougCassidy Variables holding function pointers are quite handy for getting a wee bit of functional programming in CFML. Just like with JavaScript, you have to careful not to "pollute" the global scope, which is variables for ColdFusion CFCs and CFMs.

Comment: I suppose it's like myClass::someMethod(), eh? But still, my question, is it just a matter of naming your functions: lib.func?  Or do you actually create the lib cfc?